# Top level component in React Redux application

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Don't you think that [App.js](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/examples/shopping-cart/containers/App.js) in the official redux shopping-cart example [looks more like presentational component](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0#.i0sekfgeo) despite it contains highest level containers? Is 'containers' (which is current folder) appropriate folder or may be it should be in 'components' folder with other presentational components?

Answer (score 0):

Usually I would keep my top level component `App` a presentational component because it acts like an skeleton of your app. It wouldn't cause any errors because it contains container components if that's what you are worried about.

There is no right answer on how you should structure your folders, as long as you keep things organized and well documented within your team.